# How to add Thumbnail button in frontend editor

Tags: editor

It is really Awsome plugin, great peice of work. Thank you for creating this. it has help me to create front end editor. Futher to improve editing option I want to add Button for Featured image of post. I have added button in editor but how to open set featured image popup on click of it.

There is option of insert media from which we can setup this but I want to have separate button that will only allow to set featured image same as that backend.

Please guide me on this..

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-front-end-editor/

Comment: I have Done the required.. By adding code in class-wp-front-end-editor.php

$wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
'id' => 'featuredImage',
'href' => '#',
'title' => '<span class="button-primary" title="Set Header image">Set Header image</span>',
'meta' => array(
'title' => 'Set Header image'
),
'fee' => true
) );

inside public function admin_bar_menu( $wp_admin_bar ) {

Comment: And Added jquery function inside js/tinymce.fee.js

editor.addButton( 'wp-admin-bar-featuredImage', {
title: 'featuredImage',
tooltip: 'featuredImage',
onclick: function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$( '#set-post-thumbnail' ).click();
}
} );

This may help other people..